# Самый быстрый целочисленный тип

Tags: c++

Почему целочисленный тип, меньший чем размер машинного слова, обрабатывается медленней чем тип размерностью = размеру машинного слова?

Тогда какой тип быстрей будет обрабатываться `int > T` или `int < T`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Хотел я поработать разрушителем мифов ... Не получилось. "Миф" выдержал...

Была сделана тестовая программа на C:

```
int main()
 {
  unsigned char b,c,d;
  unsigned int a;
  struct timespec t,t1;
  int i;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
  b=5; c=7; d=45;
  for(i=0;i<50000000;i++)
   {
    for(a=0;a<200;a++)
     {
      b^=c+d;
      c=d-b;
      d=b^5;
     }
   }
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);
  printf("Difference %ld %ld\n",t1.tv_sec-t.tv_sec,t1.tv_nsec-t.tv_nsec);
  printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
 }
```

Назовем ее программой 'A'. И точно такая же программа, но с переменными `unsigned int b,c,d` - программа 'B'.
При компиляции gcc с оптимизацией `-O3` получился следующий ассемблерный код основных циклов, с моими комментариями с смыслом операций:

```
      Программа А                         Программа B
.L2:                                .L2:
    movl    $200, %eax   a=200          movl    $200, %eax     a=200
.L3:                                .L3:
    addl    %r9d, %r8d   c+=d           addl    %r9d, %r8d     c+=d
    movl    %r9d, %ecx   X=d            xorl    %r8d, %ebx     b^=c
    movl    $5, %r9d     d=5            movl    %r9d, %r8d     c=d
    xorl    %r8d, %ebx   b^=c           movl    %ebx, %r9d     d=b
    subb    %bl, %cl     X-=b           subl    %ebx, %r8d     c-=b
    xorl    %ebx, %r9d   d^=b           xorl    $5, %r9d       d^=5
    subl    $1, %eax     a--            subl    $1, %eax       a--
    movl    %ecx, %r8d   c=X
    jne     .L3          for(a)         jne     .L3            for(a)
    subl    $1, %edx     i--            subl    $1, %edx       i--
    jne     .L2          for(i)         jne     .L2            for(i)

                     Результаты выполнения:
 Difference 22 -30098974                Difference 19 -697228347
 Difference 22 394100751                Difference 18 2860932
 Difference 22 -37226465                Difference 18 3254312
 Difference 22 67398660                 Difference 18 43898871
 Difference 22 -29109230                Difference 18 449544279
```

Первое, что бросается в глаза, в варианте 'A' оптимизатор вводит новую "переменную" 'X', а точнее выполняет пересылку `d` в регистр `ecx` работает с ним и потом возвращает обратно в `d`. Это связано с тем, что под переменную `d` он использует регистр R9 с младшим байтом которого независимо работать невозможно, а для вычитания он предпочитает использовать операцию той размерности, которую мы попросили. Поэтому использует `ECX`, младший байт которого доступен как `CL`

Фактически оптимизатор как с 1 байтом в данном случае выполняет только вычитание. А сложение и `XOR` он спокойно выполняет в полноразмерных, 4х байтовых регистрах, не опасаясь побочных эффектов.

Дабы быстрее развеять миф я решил заменить в варианте 'A' `subb bl,cl`, на равнозначную 4х байтовую `subl ebx,ecx`. И тут меня ждал сюрприз, без каких либо еще правок программа стала выполнятся *18* секунд, вместо *22*. Процессор (в моем случае Core i7) выполняет вычитание в 1 байтовых регистрах медленнее, чем в "полных", 4х байтовых. После я попробовал так же операции `add и xor` и получил те же результаты.

После этого я сделал программу 'C' с типами `unsigned long long`, компилятор сгенерил нормальные 64х битные операции, которые показали те же 18 секунд. Т.е. в 64х битном режиме операции с int и long работают одинаково быстро. Проверка с типом `short int`, т.е. c 16 битным дала 22 секунды, как и с 8-битным.

> Итого: Современные процессоры Intel, как минимум Core i7, выполняет операции в однобайтовых регистрах медленнее, чем в 4х байтовых, почему - спросите архитекторов процессоров Intel. Кроме того, в архитектуре x86 только с 4 из 16 регистров общего назначения можно работать как с байтовыми, следовательно оптимизатору приходится генерить более сложный код для обеспечения работы с такими типами.

Comment: Хорошее исследование. Только надо не забывать, что если обрабатываемых данных много и доступ к ним "непредсказуем" (например, списки в куче или хэш-таблицы), то лимитирующим  становится  размещении данных в кэше CPU. Т.е. чем меньше размерность данных, тем больше их может поместиться в кэш. А для программ без требований к памяти все верно.

Comment: @Mike: Вы бы лучше сравнили на других архитектурах. [x86 — извращение](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/14/229387.aspx).

Comment: @VladD Хоть она и извращение, как вы говорите, но самая распространенная, на "обычных" компах. И к сожалению у меня под руками других архитектур нет

Comment: @Mike: Процитирую первое же предложение по ссылке: «due to its overwhelming popularity, people think that the x86 way is the normal way and that everybody else is weird» :) (У меня тоже, к сожалению, другой архитектуры под руками нет.)

Comment: @avp Да, может стоило упомянуть, но тогда боюсь исследование бы затянулось на несколько дней и на  выходе был бы труд плохо подходящий по формату SO :)

Comment: @VladD Я помню как 400 MHz dec alpha, с пассивным охлаждением, жала wav в mp3 в реальном времени, а x86 того времени минуту за 3 делал. Если не изменяет память пни тогда 2 или 3 были...

Comment: @Mike: Угу, а одного Spark Station хватало, чтобы раздавать интернет целому городу.

Comment: Только с тех пор x86 внутри стал *самым настоящим* RISC (и по моему даже управляемым потоком данных)

Comment: @Mike Какую литературу можете посоветовать почитать что бы разбираться в этом лучше?

Comment: `unsigned long int` 64-битный? Ты в линуксе что ли? Вроде у всех виндовых компиляторов он 32-битный.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, в линухе, 64bit система. Хз как на 32 битной будет

Comment: @Mike, по идее, `long long` вместо `long int` более универсально.

Answer (score 5):

Предположу, что потому что при всех операциях он всё равно расширяется до int'а.

Скорее всего int самый быстрый. В x32 это даже писалось в книге, правда, не по си.
А вот для x64 имеет смысл проверить - вероятно будет или int32, или int64.

Хотя, проверить в любом случае имеет смысл - зачем спрашивать то, что можно измерить?

Comment: Не факт что расширяется. Вполне встречается такое mov byte ptr [esp+474h+var_4], bl и эта программа 100% была на C++. Просто операция с al/ah или ax может быть медленнее, чем с eax.

Comment: al/ah не медленнее, на современных камнях почти все подобные операции за 1 такт выполняются. Шина то же не должна сильно страдать, данные по любому в кеш заранее притащит.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я про арифметические операции говорил.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Однако я ошибался на счет скорости байтовых регистров. Подробнее - в моем исследовании ниже ...

Comment: @Qweriy, "писалось в книге, правда, не по си", а в какой книге? :)

Comment: @MrPrank, не помню точно. Но книга была по VB6, а тип, естественно, назывался Long (в котором 32 бита), затем Integer (16 бит) и Byte.