# Генерация без повторений. Как ускорить проверку на дубликаты?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

С помощью гпсп mt19937_64 генерирую 800 тысяч чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 30 миллионов. Каждое генерируемое число должно быть исключительным, то есть с каждой генерацией приходится сравнивать полученное число со всеми уже сгенерированными:

```
unsigned array[800 000]; 

for (int i = 0; i < 800 000; i++)
{

  generate_again:      

  buffer = uid(rng);     // генерация в буфер

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) // сравниваем с каждым сгенерированным числом
    {
        if (buffer == array[j])
        {
            goto generate_again; // если такое число уже есть - переход к генерации
        }
    }
    array[i] = pepper; // если число исключительное - записываем в массив
}
```

Этот процесс занимает 16 минут. Есть ли способ ускорить этот процесс?
Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно хранить полученные данные в дереве(`std::set`) — получите O(lgn) на вставку и поиск или в hash таблице(`std::unordered_set`), где вставка тоже довольно дёшева(не помню сколько точно), а поиск O(1). Это гарантировано ускорит процесс.

Если же оставить массив, то можно к нему добавить `std::bitset` на 30 000 000 бит. Выставлять i-й бит, если i было сгенерировано, и, соответственно, проверять на каждой итерации, не было ли оно сгенерировано. Это тоже должно ускорить процесс.

Comment: Идею с bitset хорошо понял, сейчас попробую реализовать. А вот с хэшами не очень. Для каждого генерируемого числа нужно подсчитать хэш и заполнить ими таблицу?

Comment: +1, но почему не `std::unsorted_set`?

Comment: Да просто битовый вектор на 30 млн бит (3750000 байт) и цикл `while (n < 800000) { v = newnumber(); if (такого еще нет) array[n++] = v;}`

Comment: @VladD, я его и имел в виду под «хэш таблицей», просто написать явно забыл :)

Comment: @StayCool, обновил ответ

Answer (score 7):

прежде всего, уберите проверку проходом по массиву. Это отнимает линейное время от числа чисел. Если у вас всего 30 млн вариантов и достаточно памяти, кладите их в массив флагов. Это будет стоить примерно 30Мб. Ещё одна оптимизация по памяти - упаковка флагов в битовую маску. Один флаг тогда занимает один бит. Такой подход будет стоить в 8 раз дешевле. Имея 30Мб/8 (~4Мб) массив флагов, вы можете делать проверку существования числа за константное время. Это значительно ускорит процесс. Но имеется ещё одна проблема: будут коллизии при достаточно большом количестве уже полученных чисел.

доступ к флагу:

```
arr[i/8] & (1 << (i%8)) != 0
```

установка флага:

```
arr[i/8] |= (1 << (i%8))
```

Стоить отметить, что именно такой способ хранения информации о файле принят в фс NTFS, да и в некоторых других тоже.

Comment: Отлично. А элемент битового массива лучше делать размером с машинное слово (32 или 64 бита). Ну и делить/брать остаток от размера элемента конечно. На 800к операций на платформе intel разница в скорости будет существенной. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476191/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF/476295#476295

Answer (score 5):

800 000 / 30 000 000 = 2.6% это очень много. Могу предложить такой вариант:

Если вам нужно все 30 000 000 тогда алгоритм будет работать больше. Но если 100 000 хватить, тогда он будет работать быстрее. И так шаги

1. Создать массив А с 30 000 000 элементами
2. Заполнить массив Элементами от 0 до 30 000 000
3. Сделать цикл от K = 0 до 800 000 (можно и больше, даже 30 000 000, но не меньше)
4. в цикле берем рандомно число R = от K до 30 000 000
5. Меняем местами числа A[K] <=> A[R]
6. после завершении цикла берете первые 800 000 элементов.

6*. Если в шаг (3) делали больше чем 800 000 шагов цикла, то можно в пункт (6) начать из другого индекса.

Comment: Т. е. в более абстрактных терминах сгенерировать случайную перестановку из 1..30 000 000 (Фишер-Йейтс/Дуршенфельд, `O(N)`) и взять первые 800 000 её элементов. Если такое потребление памяти допустимо, проще подхода просто нет.

Comment: Вы правы. Это намного проще чем всё остальное.

Answer (score 4):

800'000 чисел - это довольно мало. Их можно класть в `std::set`, тогда получится сортированный набор уникальных чисел.

```
std::mt19937_64 prng(seeds);
std::uniform_int_distribution distribution(0, 30'000'000);
std::set<int> set;
while (set.size() < 800'000)
  set.insert(distribution(prng));
```

Далее можно просто переложить эти числа в вектор и перемешать их:

```
std::vector<int> v(begin(set), end(set));
std::shuffle(begin(v), end(v), prng);
```

Либо можно класть числа сразу и в set, и в вектор:

```
std::set<int> set;
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(800'000);
while (v.size() < 800'000) {
  auto x = distribution(prng);
  if (set.insert(x).second) v.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: тут есть еще один подвох. Если человеку нужно не из 800 000 значений и именно из 30 000 000. Тогда как быть?

Comment: да, значения должны быть именно от 0 до 30 миллионов. Это адреса байтов в файле размеров 30МБ. 30 мегабайт - 30 миллионов адресов. Если числа будут до 800тысяч то я запишу всю информацию в начало файла, что неприемлимо

Comment: @Abyx да вы правы, это функция поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Создать массив неповтворяющихся псевдослучайных чисел можно, например, так:
1. Записать в массив `A` **H=2<sup>R</sup>=33 554 432**, `R=25` подряд идущих чисел.
2. Задать верхний предел диапазона индексов `h = H-1` (или сколько надо -   например, 29999999) и его разрядность `r = 25`.
3. Сгенерировать очередное случайное число `P` в диапазоне **0..H-1**.
4. Вычислить `p = P >> (R-r);`.
5. Если `p > h`, то перейти к п. 3.
6. Записать **A<sub>p</sub>** в массив результата.
7. Присвоить **A<sub>p</sub> = A<sub>h-1</sub>;**.
8. Уменьшить диапазон индексов: `h--;`.
9. Если `h == ((1 << (r-1)) - 1)`, то уменьшить разрядность: `r--;`.
10. Повторить пп. 3-9 до заполнения массива результата (800 000 раз).