# Перевести число double в его двоичное представление в памяти компьютера

Tags: c

> На вход подается число типа double, возможно отрицательное, нужно
>   посчитать колличество едниничных бит ИМЕННО в
>   представлении компьютера. НЕ используя С++, онли С.

Пробовал брать отдельно каждый байт от double и отдельно работать с каждым его битом, как с обычным целым числом, но что то не срослось:

```
int result(0);
unsigned char *gg = (unsigned char*)&x;

for (int i(0); i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j(0); j < 8; j++)
    {
        result += *gg & 1;
        *gg >>= 1;
    }
    gg++;
}
```

Может кто нибудь уже сталкивался с похожей задачей?

Comment: Я могу предложить метод, но он зависит от порядка байт на вашей машине. Нужно заранее знать, little-endian или big-endian у вас там.

Comment: К сожалению программа будет запускаться на разных ПК, так что, думаю, это не вариант.

Comment: Ясно. Тогда придётся уточнить задачу. Если число уже дано в виде double, то в чём именно была проблема разбить его на байты? Код типа `for (i=0; i<8; i++) c[i] = *((unsigned char *)&x+i);` (где c - отдельные байты, а x - исходно число) не подходит? Понятно, что он зависит от порядка байт, но его можно заранее вычислить и сделать корректировку.

Comment: @Zealint А зачем корректировать по порядку байт. сказано же "вывести так, как лежит в памяти". Т.е. как вы и предлагаете побайтно идем и печатаем отдельные байты. Результат на разных машинах может отличаться - и это правильно, оно же по другому лежит

Comment: сейчас немного дополню пост

Comment: @Mike, тут Вы правы, но я по опыту ответов на подобные вопросы подозреваю, что человек хочет не совсем то, что спрашивает. Наводящими вопросами я узнаю, что именно ему нужно.

Comment: @Grenny, ну вот видите, задача-то ДРУГАЯ! Это совершенно другая задача и мой код её полностью решает (далее отдельные байты просто подставляем под алгоритм из [этой статьи](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimgfPNlY7MAhVHkiwKHTCYCP0QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F276957%2F&usg=AFQjCNE6Z3255BJGsaovY16if3DRtahYUw&bvm=bv.119408272,d.bGg))

Comment: Я относительно новичок и статьи на хабре с этим адским кодом читаются очень трудно. А почему мой алгоритм не работает?

Comment: @Zealint: Если речь идёт лишь о _количестве_ единичных битов, то от порядка байт это зависеть не должно.

Comment: Так это было сказано УЖЕ ПОСЛЕ, того, как я задал вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если исправить ошибки, то будет работать.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int result=0, i, j;
  double x = -1234e56;
  unsigned char *gg = (unsigned char*)&x;
  unsigned char tmp;

  for (i=0; i < 8; i++) {
    tmp = *gg;
    for (j=0; j < 8; j++) {
      result += (tmp & 1);
      tmp >>= 1;
    }
    gg++;
  }

  printf ("%u", result);

  return 0;
}
```

**UPD**: Также рекомендую ознакомиться с [этим](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) ресурсом. Там можно перевести любое число в плавающий формат (одинарной и двойной точности) и вывести в любом виде, даже побитово (формат вывода выбирается на странице).

**UPD2**: [О подсчёте единичных битов в числе](https://habrahabr.ru/post/276957/).

Comment: Работало оно и без этих исправлений, но почему то даже с ними она работает не правильно(если я конечно все правильно понимаю). На вход подаю число -10.0 в ответе получаю 4, но если это же число перевести как long то получается 30 единиц, по логике в double их должно быть 62

Comment: @Grenny double это число с плавающей точкой, оно хранится совершенно по другому. хранится всегда положительное значение мантисы, показатель степени и один бит обозначающий знак. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: аааа, точно, гениально :) вот как раз и получается 4 единичных бита :) спасибо большое!

Comment: Да, пожалуй мои исправления чисто профессиональные. Во-первых, нельзя затирать исходное число x (а у вас затиралось) - это просто правило хорошего тона. Во-вторых, у вас было не совсем на Си, я сделал так, чтобы 5 компиляторов (TinyC, VC, Clang, Intel C и GCC) полностью соглашались с тем, что это Си, а не С++.

Comment: В следующий раз, пожалуйста, СРАЗУ задавайте вопрос как есть, не уводя в сторону (типа сначала двоичную запись получить, потом - совершенно иная задача - число бит посчитать).

Comment: Сделал UPD, добавил ссылку на полезный сайт.

Comment: Понял, в следующий раз буду задавать как надо) а на счет C++ кода: наш препод разрешает использовать мелкие плюшки из C++ чисто для удобства, а вот использование ООП возможностей С++ ему бы уже не понравилось

Comment: Вот только вопрос, а почему если я пишу -1, то он выводит 11 единичных битов?

Comment: Зайдите, пожалуйста, на сайт, что я дал в своём ответе, введите туда -1, выберите double и выберите двоичный вывод. Увидите сами.

Comment: @Grenny Вы статью про double прочитали, ссылку на которую я вам скинул ? Там как раз нарисовано как хранится 1. степень 0x3ff - 10 бит и еще отрицательный знак

Comment: я бы ещё для ускорения предложил использовать __builtin_popcount а не цикл.

Comment: Вы бы в этот ответ ссылочку на свою статью в хабре о подсчтете бит вставили.

Answer (score 2):

Короткий вариант.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  double x = -10;
  int result=0;
  uint64_t X=*((uint64_t *)&x);
  while(X) {
     result++;
     X&=X-1;
  }
  printf ("%u", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: По поводу быстроты этого алгоритма я бы [очень сильно поспорил](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiawqCCnY7MAhVEiSwKHSnTDdwQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F276957%2F&usg=AFQjCNE6Z3255BJGsaovY16if3DRtahYUw&bvm=bv.119408272,d.bGg).

Comment: @Zealint Ок, не всегда быстрый. Но работа сразу с uint64 (для платформы intel) заведомо быстрее, т.к. операции с однобайтными регистрами медленнее. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476191/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF/476295#476295

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
struct s
{
 uint32_t u1;
 uint32_t u2;
}__attribute__((packed));

union
{
  double d;
  struct s;
}v;

int pop(uint32_t x)
{
  x = x-((x>>1) & 0x55555555);
  x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x>>2) & 0x33333333);
  x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
  x = x + (x >> 8);
  x = x + (x >> 16);
  return x & 0x0000003F;
}

{
 int amount_bit;
 v.d = -10;
 amount_bit = pop(v.s.u1);
 amount_bit += pop(v.s.u2);
}
```

Comment: Согласен по стандарту double 64 бита.

Answer (score 1):

Быстрый вариант для 64 битных систем.

Но подсчитывает только 15 бит дальше идет переполнение.

```
   int pop (int16_t x)
   {
    uint64_t y;
    y = x * 0x0002000400080010;
    y = y & 0x1111111111111111;
    y = y * 0x1111111111111111;
    y = y >> 60;
    return y;
   }
```

> "Алгоритмические трюки для программиста" Генри Уоррен

Comment: Иногда как-то неправильно считает (хоть и быстрее всех). Например, для 0, 1, 10 правильно (как и все остальные тут), а для -1 или 3.14 неправильно.